# Add DOM data attribute value, each button has different data value

Tags: jquery

I have Issue with my jquery code. I have each button different unique ID and I need to set data attribute value and other function has to receive that that DOM data attribute value. At the moment I get console undefined.

My html code:

```
<div class="booked-appt-list shown" style="display: block;">
    <div class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title ">
        <span class="timeslot-time">
            <span class="timeslot-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
            <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;14:45 – 16:45</span>
        </span>
        <span class="timeslot-people">
            <button id="ddPrefixBtn_12" data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Exclusive studio - #KO" data-timeslot="1445-1645" data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
                <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
                <span class="button-timeslot">14:45 – 16:45</span><span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title ">
        <span class="timeslot-time">
            <span class="timeslot-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
            <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;17:15 – 19:15</span>
        </span>
        <span class="timeslot-people">
            <button id="ddPrefixBtn_13" data-prefix="" data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Prime studio - #SP" data-timeslot="1715-1915" data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
                <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
                <span class="button-timeslot">17:15 – 19:15</span>
                <span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="booked-serviceSwitcher calendar">
    <p>
        <i class="booked-icon booked-icon-calendar"></i>
        <select class="booked_calendar_chooser" id="change_service_booked">
            <option class="level-0" data-prefix="SP">Party</option>
            <option class="level-0" data-prefix="KO">School</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
```

My jquery code:

```
let t = $('*#ddPrefixBtn_').attr('data-title') // I try to get title ex.: Studio Suprime
let n = $('#change_service_booked').find(':selected').attr('data-prefix'); // here I find service for ex.: SP, EV.. 
$('*#ddPrefixBtn_').data('prefix', t+' - #'+n); // here i try to DOM set prefix ex.: Studio Suprime - #SP

console.log($('*#ddPrefixBtn_').data('prefix')); //gives undefined

let titleValue = $(".field-paid-service-select option").filter((i, e) => {
    return e.innerHTML.indexOf($('*#ddPrefixBtn_').data('prefix')) > -1;
}).val();

$(".field-paid-service-select").val(titleValue); // product name is in select option and it should select correct product name ex.: Studio Suprime - #SP
$(".field-paid-service-select").find('option').not(':selected').remove(); // removes others options what doesn't match
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$('*#ddPrefixBtn_')` selector does not work like you seem to think it does. It is equivalent to `#ddPrefixBtn_`, which selects the element that have the `ddPrefixBtn_` id.

Are you trying to select all elements with an id that contains `ddPrefixBtn_`? If so, you should use:

```
$('[id*=ddPrefixBtn_]')
```

If, instead, you don't need to match all, you probably want to just use regular [id selectors](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (`$('#ddPrefixBtn_12')`).

For instance, the code below works:

```js
let t = $('[id*=ddPrefixBtn]').attr('data-title') // I try to get title ex.: Studio Suprime
let n = $('#change_service_booked').find(':selected').attr('data-prefix'); // here I find service for ex.: SP, EV.. 
$('[id*=ddPrefixBtn]').data('prefix', t+' - #'+n); // here i try to DOM set prefix ex.: Studio Suprime - #SP

console.log($('[id*=ddPrefixBtn]').data('prefix')); //gives undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="booked-appt-list shown" style="display: block;">
    <div class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title ">
        <span class="timeslot-time">
            <span class="timeslot-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
            <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;14:45 – 16:45</span>
        </span>
        <span class="timeslot-people">
            <button id="ddPrefixBtn_12" data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Exclusive studio - #KO" data-timeslot="1445-1645" data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
                <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
                <span class="button-timeslot">14:45 – 16:45</span><span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title ">
        <span class="timeslot-time">
            <span class="timeslot-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
            <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;17:15 – 19:15</span>
        </span>
        <span class="timeslot-people">
            <button id="ddPrefixBtn_13" data-prefix="" data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Prime studio - #SP" data-timeslot="1715-1915" data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
                <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
                <span class="button-timeslot">17:15 – 19:15</span>
                <span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="booked-serviceSwitcher calendar">
    <p>
        <i class="booked-icon booked-icon-calendar"></i>
        <select class="booked_calendar_chooser" id="change_service_booked">
            <option class="level-0" data-prefix="SP">Party</option>
            <option class="level-0" data-prefix="KO">School</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working, console still return undefined